# Sheldon Ross: Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the very first line of this book, I am greeted by this problem

#### A communication system is to consist of n seemingly identical antennas that are to be lined up in a linear order. The resulting system will then be able to receive all incoming signals—and will be called functional—as long as no two consecutive antennas are defective. If it turns out that exactly m of the n antennas are defective, what is the probability that the resulting system will be functional?

I am able to solve it when given a value (small values tbh) for n and m like n=4 and m=2 and I have figured out that **m<=(n-m)** but I am unable to find the generalized solution to this. Any help from fellow scholars will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, line up all the working antennas. There are $n-m$ of them. Now, there $n-m+1$ spaces available for placing the defective ones, and so the number of ways of choosing $m$ spaces out of these is$${{n-m+1}\choose m}$$ Note that doing this will ensure that no two adjacent antennas are defective.

Now, the total arrangements possible are $\frac{n!}{m! (n-m)!} = {n\choose m}$ and the desired probability is
$$\frac{{n-m+1}\choose m}{n \choose m}$$